# Build tree of categories flat array

Tags: php, arrays, tree

I am looking for best solution which can convert array like below as an tree like output.

```
Array
(
  [0] => Furniture/Chair
  [1] => Furniture/Sofa/L Shaped
  [2] => Furniture/Storage/Crockery Unit
  [5] => Furniture/Sofa/1 Seater
  [7] => Furniture/Sofa/2 Seater
  [9] => Furniture/Sofa/3 Seater
  [14] => Furniture/Storage/TV Unit
)
```

The above array is dynamic array. I want this whole array convert like a tree below.

```
- Furniture
   Chair
   Sofa 
     L Shaped
     1 Seater
     2 Seater
     3 Seater
   Storage
     Crockery Unit
     TV Unit
```

But the main parent furniture is not static that also comes dynamically it may be n number of terms

Comment: And what you have tried so far. Post your attempts too

Answer (score 0):

You can approach this problem in a couple of ways. You can parse each array and create an inefficient multidimensional array from the values. Or you can build an actual tree in PHP. Here's a great SitePoint article about trees in PHP: http://www.sitepoint.com/data-structures-2/